# Retrieve specific account in truffle 5 console

Tags: web3js, truffle, dapp-development, testrpc, truffle-console

I am following a truffle tutorial where the individual users `web3.eth.accounts` to retrieve all the accounts from Ganash. However that seemed depreciated and to duplicate his results I used `web3.eth.getAccounts()` as you can see below. [image]

However a next command is ran in truffle console `web3.eth.accounts[0]` which presents account at position 1 (well the first account).

Ultimately, this is my problem as I cannot yet figure out how to accomplish the same in truffle 5.I have tried `web3.eth.getAccounts([0])` and `web3.eth.getAccounts().then(e => let firstAcc=e[0]; console.log(firstAcc));` which was suggested but neither works. Appreciate any help or guidance I could receive to assist me with this small issue.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Truffle v5 uses web3 v1 that uses promises to return values. To access the third account you have do something like this:

```
account = (await web3.eth.getAccounts())[3]
```

Now `account` contains the address.

Answer (score 2):

You should try the same as suggested by Ismael. But this will work in two cmd commands 
like this if you try only account = (await web3.eth.getAccounts())[3]. This will give you undefined . You should try like this

truffle(development) > account = (await web3.eth.getAccounts())[3]

undefined

truffle(development) > account